# How to make fmpp fail if a value cannot be found for a variable?

Tags: freemarker, fmpp

Is there a parameter to make FMPP fail when it is unable to find a value for a variable in the template? right now it just leaves the text intact with ${} if it cannot resolve a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something strange is going on there, because it **does** fail and by default even aborts the whole batch processing if you refer to an undefined variable. Also, it doesn't leave `${}`-s in the output, because all the `${` and `}` are "parsed away" before the template could do anything. So I suspect the value of those variables is indeed the string `"${}"`, or you have some tricky `#escape` in the `border`/`footer`/`header` settings, or something tricky like that. (If you can provide a minimalistic example to reproduce this, I can certainly spot the reason.)